# How to implement datatable into laravel 5.4 with ajax crud

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatable, laravel-5.4

my website contain basic CRUD operation with ajax build in, my question is, how to implement datatable? by the way, I already deploy yajra datatable

js file

```
$(function () {

    $('#example').DataTable({

});});

function manageRow(data) {
var rows = '';
$.each( data, function( key, value ) {
    rows = rows + '<tr>';
    rows = rows + '<td>'+value.title+'</td>';
    rows = rows + '<td>'+value.description+'</td>';
    rows = rows + '<td data-id="'+value.id+'">';
    rows = rows + '<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-item" class="btn btn-primary edit-item">Edit</button> ';
    rows = rows + '<button class="btn btn-danger remove-item">Delete</button>';
    rows = rows + '</td>';
    rows = rows + '</tr>';
});
$("tbody").html(rows);}
```

view

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
<thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Position</th>
     <th>Office</th>
 </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a model in Laravel
2. Create a controller for that model, register the routes

I think StackOverflow is not the place to right the application for you. If you have special questions on that, I can help you.

Comment: i tried laracast but no one willing to help,
actually i do have model and controller build in for that, i followed a tutorial from other site, but i just wanted to implement datatables

Comment: create a migration script for the model, edit the migration script and add your columns and run a migration on the database. e.g you can get all objects from the DB Model::all() for more details: [Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations) and [get the models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-models)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is really straightforward, if you follow the example it should work.
https://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/basic